# Search on multiple Google Sheets for variables

Tags: google-apps-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBwPj.png)
I have a script that searches for a specific product and shows the information regarding this product and I want to do it so that you can choose the tab from a drop down list and then type search onto it and it will find the specific product you are looking for, I would appreciate your help with this and my code is right below

```
function searchStr() {
  
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Main Sheet"); //Form Sheet
  
  var str       = formSS.getRange("F10:G11").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName("UGC").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
  {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) 
    {

    
      
      formSS.getRange("F13:G14").setValue(row[2]);
      formSS.getRange("L13:M14").setValue(row[3]);
      formSS.getRange("F16:G17").setValue(row[4]);
      formSS.getRange("L16:M17").setValue(row[5]);
      formSS.getRange("F19:G20").setValue(row[1]);
      formSS.getRange("L19:M20").setValue(row[6]);
      formSS.getRange("F22:G23").setValue(row[7]);
      formSS.getRange("L22:M23").setValue(row[8]);
      formSS.getRange("F25:G26").setValue(row[9]);
      formSS.getRange("L25:M26").setValue(row[10]);
      
      
           
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
      
    }
  }
}


function updateData() {

  var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "UGC";
  var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 1;
  var RETURN_COL_IDX = 1;
  
   var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Main Sheet"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("UGC"); //Data Sheet
  
 
  var str       = formSS.getRange("F10:G11").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName("UGC").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
     var INT_R = i+1
      
      var values1 = [[formSS.getRange("F19:G20").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F13:G14").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L13:M14").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F16:G17").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L16:M17").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L19:M20").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F22:G23").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L22:M23").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F25:G26").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("L25:M26").getValue()]];
   
 datasheet.getRange(INT_R, 2, 1, 10).setValues(values1);
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(' "Thank you for making changes ! "');
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, `formSS.getRange("F10:G11").getValues()` takes a final `s` ... however, to debug, please give a simplified copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Mike Steelson here is the [LINK] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-N36g4gLwk2ze3LXNHZJX3Y42C1YxWbFQZ2pOr8h1Kg/edit?usp=sharing) for an example script as well as what it does

Comment: @MikeSteelson I have given the link here

Comment: Where are situated Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3 ?

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: This `var str  = formSS.getRange("F10:G11").getValue();` is equivalent to this `var str   = formSS.getRange("F10").getValue();`

Comment: Mike Steelson, in the original sheet the products are divided into different tabs and I wish to select different sheets when inputting new data into the spredsheet or even editing the old one

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function onOpen(){
  const excludeSheets = ['main sheet', 'sheet6'];
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const mainSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Main Sheet");
  const cell = mainSheet.getRange('L10');
  const tabNames = spreadsheet.getSheets()
    .map(sheet=> sheet.getName())
    .filter(sheetName => excludeSheets.includes(sheetName.toLocaleLowerCase()) === false);
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(tabNames).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work because onOpen is a simple trigger and seDataValidation() requires permissions.   But this rule has become cloudy this days  with some simple triggers working as long as they are container bound and perhaps this is the case.